# LUbuntu 16.04 LTS and Radeon HD6290 - Drivers needed?

Tags: drivers, graphics, lubuntu, radeon, amd-graphics

I am running Lubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Compaq CQ58 laptop.
This laptop has a Dual Core AMD C60 CPU @ 1 GHz and ATI Radeon HD6290 GPU.
8GB ram and an SSD complete the package.

This laptop is slow and I'm trying to see of maybe the CPU is being overworked because the GPU isn't being used properly.

I can not install the drivers available here:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux

Firstly, there isn't a download for 16.04... THere is one for 15.04 and 12.04. I took the 15.04 one, close enough.

It says I haven't installed the prerequisites. I can't find some of its dependencies.

Notes say that it needs the folowing packages installed:
    gimp-help-en
    gimp-help-common
    XFree86-Mesa-libGL
    libstdc++
    libgcc
    XFree86-libs
    fontconfig
    freetype
    zlib
    gcc

I tried typing "sudo apt-get install _______" where the blank was filled in with all of the above. I think I only got the first two. It said the rest were not found.

What do I do?

Comment: Please do not install drivers meant for older version of Ubuntu- thats **exactly** how you break your system. Proprietary drivers for AMD cards are not supported in >16.04, unfortunately. *Also*, your computer is indeed very slow and I wouldn't expect much better performance regardless. Try installing a light desktop environment.

Comment: Since this is LUbuntu, I have the LXDE environment.

Comment: This laptop's performance is worse than when it originally had 2GB of RAM, a mechanical hard drive, and WIndows 8.

SIde by side, in its current configutation, its performance is worse than a Celeron 900 MHz with 2GB of RAM. Despite having two cores instead of one and 4x the RAM.

It's not like I'm going anything really intensive on it. Just running Firefox.

Comment: If you want to use AMD's proprietary drivers and have LTS support downgrade to 14.04. There isn't much else I can recommend. Try enabling/disabling 3D acceleration, or trying out Chromium.